# What effect does #define X X have in C?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, llvm-clang

In the [source code of `stdbool.h`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/stdbool_8h_source.html) in LLVM project, it reads:

```
/* Don't define bool, true, and false in C++, except as a GNU extension. */
#ifndef __cplusplus
#define bool _Bool
#define true 1
#define false 0
#elif defined(__GNUC__) && !defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
/* Define _Bool, bool, false, true as a GNU extension. */
#define _Bool bool
#define bool  bool
#define false false
#define true  true
#endif
```

In the last 4 lines there are three lines of the from `#define X X`. Why would you do that? What difference does it make? Wouldn't this force compiler to just replace, say, `true` with `true`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is, that preprocessor statements like

```
#ifdef bool
// do some stuff or define bool
#endif
```

in other c files include afterwards will work proper and not trying to redefine bool in another way like

```
#define bool int
```

which would interfere with the first definition

Answer (score 7):

```
#define X X
```

has the effect that "the pre-processor conditional"<sup>*</sup>:

```
#ifdef X
```

<strike>is "true"</strike> "succeeds".<sup>*</sup>

---

<sup>*</sup> update

Comment: Not me, but I would guess saying that a preprocessor directive is "true" got you the down vote. Some people are sticklers for accuracy.

Comment: @john: I was aware of this, that's why I put it in quotes. However it is a boolean expression in the context of pre-processing, isn't it? Do you have an idea for an alternative wording?

Comment: Ok, I think the edit should fullfill anybodys expectations in accurate wording.

Comment: And why would anyone chose it instead of just `#define X` ?

Comment: @vsz in this case it would redefine C++'s bool keyword to expand to nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It would make the difference that true, false etc are now macros. So code like this

```
#if defined(true)
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

would be affected.

Comment: You mean `#ifdef true`

Comment: @MilesRout `#ifdef true` and `#if defined(true)` are the same.

Comment: Well that's opinion, nevertheless I meant what I wrote.

Comment: @MilesRout Shorter, yes.  Clearer, not necessarily. `#ifdef` is less general. `defined X` can be combined with other expressions.  And I personally think `#if !defined X` is less likely to be misread than `#ifndef`.

Comment: @MilesRout `#if defined` has the advantage over `#ifdef` that it allows you to add `#elif` cases